# Anonymous caller does not have storage.objects.get

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, http-headers, google-cloud-storage, urlfetch

On Google App Engine (GAE) written in Python.

I am trying to issue an http post to cloud-speech-to-text api and using URI audio source (Google Cloud Storage Bucket Objects).

I am using the following headers;

```
Authorization: BASIC encoded_base64(username:password)
```

But I still keep getting an error response below:

> {
>     "error": {
>       "code": 403,
>       "message": "Anonymous caller does not have storage.objects.get access to bucket_of_secrets/four_score_seven_years.flac.",
>       "status": "PERMISSION_DENIED"
>     }
>   }

So I have a couple of questions;

1. Does BASIC Authorization Header work in Google HTTP API?
2. What `username:password` should I use? Is it my GCP account email and password? i.e. `handsome_dude@gmail.com:deluded_fool`

Where `handsome_dude@gmail.com` is the username and `deluded_fool` is the password.

I've tried setting the bucket objects to be public readable and of course the http call works... but I would rather avoid setting my bucket objects public readable.

Here's a sample Curl request:

```
curl -X POST 

https://speech.googleapis.com/v1/speech:longrunningrecognize?key=<secret_api_key> -d @sample.json -H "Content-Type: application/json, Authorization:  Basic base64encodedusername:password"
```

Here's a snippet in my python code using urlfetch:

```
url_post = urlfetch.fetch(url=speech_to_text_url_post, payload=json.dumps(data_to_post), method=urlfetch.POST, headers={"Content-Type" : "application/json", "Authorization" : "Basic "+encoded_user_password})
```

Comment: Note also that best practices would suggest that you now change your password, since you have sent it to a service in an unexpected way and it has potentially been written to that service's internal log files as a result.  The possibility of compromise is negilgible but not technically zero.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

> 1.Does BASIC Authorization Header work in Google HTTP API?

No, It is not working on Google APIs.
You need to attach OAuth2.0 accessToken to Authorization Header as bearer token like `Authorization: Bearer ${yourAccessToken}`.

I have 2 recommendations to develop some application running on gae.

1. Use [ClientLibrary](https://cloud.google.com/speech-to-text/docs/reference/libraries) to call Google APIs.
2. You can use `AppEngineDefaultCredential` to call Google APIs.
   Do not forget to set permissions to your `AppEngineDefaultServiceAccount (${projectId}@appspot.gserviceaccount.com)` before issue your request. You can configure those permissions on IAM page in [cloud console](https://console.cloud.google.com/).

Also I recommend you to read this page about [How to authenticate your api call](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2).

Comment: Thanks for the confirmation and the alternative solutions. 

Just a quick question, as this is my first time working on GAE. On your #2 solution. Does AppEngineDefaultCredential work on HTTP API requests or is that for ClientLibrary API calls?

Comment: @JamesChing Works for both. The App Engine default service account provides the same type of credentials that the client libraries consume/generate.

Answer (score 7):

If you want to grant public access, you can make data public.

https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/access-control/making-data-public

But **the best way** is generate **Signed Urls**, this way you can grant limit time access to an object.

https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/access-control/signed-urls

Answer (score 2):

For me, the issue was using role "Storage Legacy Object Reader", that, for whatever reason, was suggested. Changing it to "Storage Object Viewer" solved the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I landed here because I forgot to run

```
./google-cloud-sdk/bin/gcloud init
```

from the [Installation Guide](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/docs/install).