# Set Google Cloud Images to Public from Private while using Multer

Tags: javascript, file-upload, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-storage, multer

I recently switched over from deprecated multer-gcs to [multer-google-storage](https://www.npmjs.com/package/multer-google-storage). I have it mostly running, but cannot figure out how to make the files public. Is there a variable that I can set in the .env file? Right now I get the following when I go to the image page:

```
<Error>
<Code>AccessDenied</Code>
<Message>Access denied.</Message>
<Details>
Anonymous caller does not have storage.objects.get access to example-app.appspot.com/xxx-yyy-zzz
</Details>
</Error
```

**My code looks like this, and is properly saving everything, except that images are private:**

```
const multer = require('multer');
var multerGoogleStorage = require("multer-google-storage");

dotenv.load({ path: '.env' });

var uploadHandler = multer({
  storage: multerGoogleStorage.storageEngine()
});

app.post('/sell', uploadHandler.any(), homeController.postSellPage);
```

**.env File**

```
GCS_BUCKET=example-project.appspot.com
GCLOUD_PROJECT=example-project
GCS_KEYFILE=./example-project-firebase-adminsdk-xxx.json
```

Answer (score 0):

There are some options how to make the access public, so I would recommend you to take a look at the following doc and other posts on the community, on how to achieve that.

After that, you should be able to choose the best option for you and which one to follow.

- [Allow Public Read access on a GCS
  bucket?](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/access-control/making-data-public)
- [Anonymous caller does not have
  storage.objects.get](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40232188/allow-public-read-access-on-a-gcs-bucket)
- [Making data
  public](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56302658/anonymous-caller-does-not-have-storage-objects-get)

Let me know if the information helped you!