# Private access to home page

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-signin

Newbie question: I am trying to publish my first web site on GCP.
It works fine when I set public access, but I want to control access rights via Google sign-in.
Any attempt to load the home page index.html raises
*Anonymous caller does not have storage.objects.get access*.
This page contains the required scripts and sign-in button, but it can't give access to the home page itself. The web site is set with uniform access control.
TIA and best regards,
Robert.

Comment: Perhaps [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56302658/anonymous-caller-does-not-have-storage-objects-get) can help. It appears to be an issue with permissions, verify the scopes of your app

Comment: More info: the failed test above is run under my bucket-owner google account.

Comment: This is a simple static web-site, I did not specify any particular scope.

Comment: How are you enabling Google Sign-In for your site (in your code or via IAP)? Edit your question with more details.

Comment: The scripts embedded in the home page are expected to enable Google sign-in. I don't use IAP, but may be I should.

Comment: I follow the Google guidelines from [link](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/sign-in#before_you_begin)

Comment: You may want to look into using OAUTH2 to accomplish this
[Setting up OAuth2.0][1]
[Using OAuth2.0 for Web Server Applications][2]


  [1]: https://support.google.com/cloud/answer/6158849?hl=en
  [2]: https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/web-server?_gac=1.247131440.1586437475.EAIaIQobChMI97XTjbTb6AIVDp6fCh34qguBEAAYASAAEgJBM_D_BwE&_ga=2.23563834.1606303968.1588595302-1590434231.1584445337

Comment: Unless I misunderstood something, OAUTH2 should not be required to access a static web site. I don't require any user credential to validate a server transaction of any kind.

Comment: I only want the user to be identified via his GoogleId to be able to read the pages.